# Cisco Router 1002f Sfp Port to Cisco swtich c3750 gigabit port

Tags: cisco, router, layer1, cable, sfp

an anyone please instruct me how to connectCcisco router 1002f SFP ports to gigabit ports?

I have an RJ45 port on switch side and an SFP port on router side. I like to use switch as dump switch. I haven't configured anything I also have RJ45 connector when I try to connect them I see ports administrative down on router side. is there any special connector do I need?

Comment: Put one end of the cable in each device? You really should provide more details on what you're actually trying to achieve, which problems you're running into, what configurations you're using, etc. As it is, we can only guess what information you're looking for.

Comment: Hey Teun, I apologizes for that. I have rj45 port on  switch side and sfp port on router side I like to use switch as dump switch. I haven't configured anything I also have rj45 connector when I try to connect them I see ports administrative down on router side. is there  any special connector do I need ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use an SFP module and cable that is of the same standard as what you have on the switch. That is probably a `GLC-T` SPF module. You insert the SFP module in the SFP interface and connect the cable between the devices.

You must also configure the interfaces. Typically, you will either enable routing on the switch and configure a routed interface, or you will configure it as a trunk and configure subinterfaces on the router.

Comment: Hi Ron,  I do not have sfp cable. I have cat5 cable to use.  so basically one side of sfp  ports and one side of gig ports i belive we need rj45 connector and i also i have one but i am still unable to connect them.

Comment: What I am saying is that if you use the correct SFP module, you use your cable between the router and switch. You need an SFP module for your SFP interface.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/GLC-T-Cisco-1000BASE-T-Transceiver-Module/dp/B0000C3GWT ( i am taking about this)

Comment: OK, then you should be able to use a standard UTP cable between the router ans switch. Simply configure the interfaces for how you need them.

Comment: do I need that converter on both side or just on router side?

Comment: There is no converter. You have a module that you put in the SFP slot that contains a 1000BASE-T interface that is the same thing that is built into your switch. You can then use a standard UTP cable between them (within the UTP standards).

Comment: the sfp converter was faulty it works with new one.